# MySQL multiple select with different wheres in single query

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

First of, at the moment I am forced to use MySQL despite it being deprecated. I am very well aware of that fact. Hopefully you guys can still help me with my sql syntax.

I am trying to access several columns from some different tables. Problem is, some of the columns require a different where clause than the last column I need, and the where clause for the last column requires info from the rest of the query so I cannot split it up into multiple queries, I've tried.

I cannot use union because one select statement selects four columns, and the other one selects one column.

Query:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT inventory.Quantity, itemtypes.Itemtypename, 
itemtypes.ItemtypeID, inventory.ItemID
FROM inventory JOIN itemtypes ON inventory.ItemtypeID = itemtypes.ItemtypeID
JOIN sets ON inventory.SetID = sets.SetID
WHERE inventory.ItemtypeID = itemtypes.ItemtypeID
AND itemtypes.Itemtypename = 'Set'
AND sets.SetID = '".$setid."')
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT sets.Setname
FROM sets JOIN inventory ON sets.SetID = inventory.ItemID
WHERE sets.SetID = inventory.ItemID)
```

This is what I tried to use, with no success. I cannot seem to find any other way of linking to different select statements without using multiple queries (with due to the structure of my PHP file, is impossible to do properly). The rest of the file will work, if only this problem gets solved. Hopefully you guys can help me with this, please let me know if this is even possible to do. Let me know if you need to see my PHP code as well. $setid is derived from a get in the file and contains a value existing in the database.

Comment: MySQL is not deprecated! From where the hell do you have that? Certain functions in the API were replaced by newer ones, that's all.

Comment: To the question: Sample data and desired output sure help. And you don't need to repeat your join condition in the where clause. And what different where clauses are you talking about anyway? Your query can be perfectly written in one single query, not even union is required. Very unclear question...

Comment: @fancypants I'll try to explain the difference with the two where clauses. It all centers around sets.SetID = '".$setid."' and sets.SetID = inventory.ItemID. $setid is way different than inventory.ItemID. $setid is basically a set that contains several more sets, sets with the same ID as inventory.ItemID. If i use Setname in the upper Select clause i will get the setname from the $setid set, which i do not want. That is why im trying to get all the setnames from the sets inside that one, where SetID = selected ItemIDs inside $setid. I agree that its confusing.

Answer (score 0):

May be, you can try like this. It works fine in SQL Server.

```
SELECT TMP1.Quantity,TMP1.Itemtypename, TMP1.ItemtypeID, TMP1.ItemID, TMP2.Setname
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT 
inventory.Quantity, 
itemtypes.Itemtypename, 
itemtypes.ItemtypeID, 
inventory.ItemID
FROM inventory 
JOIN itemtypes ON inventory.ItemtypeID = itemtypes.ItemtypeID
JOIN sets ON inventory.SetID = sets.SetID
WHERE inventory.ItemtypeID = itemtypes.ItemtypeID
AND itemtypes.Itemtypename = 'Set'
AND sets.SetID = '".$setid."'
) AS TMP1,
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
sets.Setname
FROM sets 
JOIN inventory ON sets.SetID = inventory.ItemID
WHERE sets.SetID = inventory.ItemID
) AS TMP2
```

Hope this is what you want. Your question seems very ambiguous.

Comment: Hi @Aditya and thanks for your quick answer! It's definitely a step in the right direction. However i need to ask one more thing. In the second where clause wher it says WHERE sets.SetID = inventory.ItemID, it takes the All ItemIDs from the database. What i need is for it to take just the ItemIDs selected from the first select clause. Is this a possible thing to do or would i need additional queries for that?

Comment: Why do you need the separate queries? simply add your ItemId in first select clause as it seems there is no difference in filtering or say in where condition. It would be easier to do like that.

Comment: It would be easier if you add a screenshot of your sample dataset from both tables & the desired output.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but the problem has been solved. You both were right, I did not need two different select clauses, 1 was enough. Apparently, the inventory.SetID and the sets.SetID were not completely identical as there were entries in inventory that did not exist in sets. I switched from sets.SetID = '".$setid."' to inventory.SetID = '".$setid."'" and it worked like a charm :) I appreciate both your help, thanks for helping me despite my poorly phrased and ambiguous question. I'll try to be more detailed next time i need help.